# Do we have online IDE for Progress 4GL?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I am newbie for progress 4GL language and I would like to know any online IDE for doing exercise program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already answered there's an online snippet tool much like JSFiddle for JavaScript. But for a better experience try the classroom edition that's pretty much the real deal but free of charge. (It does however install as a desktop application the way any Progress IDE would).

https://www.progress.com/oedk

Answer (score 3):

ABL dojo (https://abldojo.services.progress.com/) is online IDE for ABL code.

Comment: while abldojo is very useful for quick snippets, it is definitely not an IDE